# How can i edit an image to make it shake in the video editor?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to add a bulldozer shaking super fast for a video i'm editing and i  don't know how to make the effect. I tried transform and adjust each frame to move over and over but it just didn't save the changes and didn't work for some reason. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Just to clarify completely.. do you want the dozer to shake, or the camera to shake? Or do you want  the final 2D render to shake?

Comment: just the dozer, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by keyframing object location and giving it a noise F-curve modifier. I chose my camera to add some shake into it.

[image: Add location keyframe]

Select the object you want to shake. Press <kbd>i</kbd> and choose Location to keyframe the object location.

[image: Go to Graph editor]

Keep your object selected and go to Graph editor. Shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image: Add Noise F-Curve Modifier]

Select the dimension you want to shake your object to. I chose Z but you can do this to all dimensions if you want to. Select Key and under Add F-Curve Modifier you find Noise.

[image: Adjust the strength]

From Modifiers panel you can adjust the strength. If the panel is not visible you can press <kbd>n</kbd> key. You can play with other settings if you want to.

[image: Result]

Just play the animation and you have some shaking.

### Video editor

In Video editor you can keyframe the offset location of your image or image sequence as can be seen in image below. Everything else is the same.

[image: Video editor]

Comment: is this done in vfx?

Comment: I added little bit more info about how to do it in video editor. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yep, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out this tutorial by Ian Hubert and use those techniques to either animate the camera or bulldozer.

[Animate Handheld Cameras in Blender - Lazy Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9EUFud9zGE) There is a slower version linked in the comments where he explains what he's doing in a more detailed manner.

Comment: While the information on the link might be helpful, This site aims to have answers that stand on their own. Please outine the main ideas and worflow. If the link disappears or changes your answer will not be useful anymore.

Comment: The reason I linked the video as opposed to writing out a tutorial I the answer is that I do not have the time to do so currently. Someone is more than welcome to either edit my answer or write their own answer based on the video. I am unable to do so and figured a video would at least help people while it is up and not giving an answer because I don't have the time to create a tutorial myself.

Comment: If you don't want to write an answer, it's fine. Use comments instead.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll remember that for next time.